# How to open sql notebook saved as markdown as an interactive notebook again?

Tags: sql, azure-notebooks

I just started using azure data studio because i wanted to store my sql code as a notebook.
When saving it i saved it as markdown and now when i open i can't get the interactive notebook layout that i was working with. How do i get back the notebook format?

I tried to save another notebook as a .net interactive notebook. Still when i open it, it only gives me code.

I have no programming experience whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Studio supports both standard Markdown files and interactive notebooks. When you save a file as Markdown, it will be treated as a plain text document. To work with interactive notebooks in Azure Data Studio, you need to save your content in the correct format.

Here's how to create and work with interactive notebooks:

Create a new notebook in Azure Data Studio as follows:
Go to File, then click on New Notebook, as shown below:

[image]

Click on Code, select SQL as the kernel, attach to the server, and write the SQL script as required, as shown below:

[image]

Save the notebook, and it will save as a notebook with the `.ipynb` extension. Open it with Azure Data Studio, as shown below:

[image]

It will open as a notebook, as shown below:

[image]